# How can i split text and insert into SQL Server (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox like this
"AAA#BBB#CCC
DDD#EEE#FFF"
I want to use Vb.net split text and insert into SQL table like this:
Insert into table A (MAIN, REASON, RESULT) VALUES (AAA, BBB, CCC)
Insert into table A (MAIN, REASON, RESULT) VALUES (DDD, EEE, FFF)

Please help me

Comment: When posting questions, try to explain what you've tried and what the problem you're facing is. Even better, with some of your code. This question is quite vague and uninformative and may get voted down or even closed as a duplicate. Also, you are asking two questions; please keep them separate. You can easily find these answers to these questions on SO if you search for each issue in turn.

Comment: Splitting text and inserting data into a database are two completely unrelated. You need to break your process down into the actual constituent parts and then determine what part(s) you actually have an issue with. You can post one question here per part, not one question for multiple parts. Can you split text? If so, do it and then leave that part out of your question. If not, ask about that specifically, with no reference to the database. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily .net provides String.Split() method. You must use parameters to avoid sql injection. The data is coming from the user.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    TextBox1.Text = "AAA#BBB#CCC DDD#EEE#FFF"
    Dim split1 = TextBox1.Text.Split() 'no parameters split by space
    'results in an array of 2 elements
    Dim DataForInsert1 = split1(0).Split("#"c) 'small c indicates to compiler that this is a Char
    Dim DataForInsert2 = split1(1).Split("#"c)
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection String"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert Into TableA (MAIN, REASON, RESULT) Values (@Main, @Reason, @Result);")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Main", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = DataForInsert1(0)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Reason", SqlDbType.VarChar, 400).Value = DataForInsert1(1)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Result", SqlDbType.VarChar, 400).Value = DataForInsert1(2)
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Parameters("@Main").Value = DataForInsert2(0)
        cmd.Parameters("@Reason").Value = DataForInsert2(1)
        cmd.Parameters("@Result").Value = DataForInsert2(2)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
```

Comment: Well, you learn something new every day, even in a language I've been coding in for many years: I did not know that you could compound `Using`s like that. As in, `cmd` and `cn`. Nice!

Comment: @SteveCinq I learned it from jmcilhinney. In C# `using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())`  
`using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())`  
`{}`